# How to find a specific class in Dynamics 365?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-operations

I'm new on Microsoft Dynamics 365 programming and I've a question that in fact it's consuming me a lot!

Well, I want to make a little customization in code at **Fixed Asset Module**.

I'm at **FixedAsset -> Fixed Assets Jounal**, but I don't know how to find in  **Visual Studio**, at the AOT (Application Object Tree)  the class that contains the codes related to FixedAssetsJournal.

How can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations development! Discovering where things are and where you should be is one of the challenges of AX development.

For a good place to start from the front-end/UI is to right click, go to Form information -> Form name:LedgerJournalTrans.

[image]

You will see a form slide out on the right side. At the bottom of that form is a fast-tab for Administration; opening that will show you several artifacts that you can view to see where in the AOT this particular form is located. From the form you can dive into tables that back it and classes that run business logic on it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It helped me out to findind the code! But when I right-click in that form at AOT to add extension and then be able to editing the code, the View Code option keeps not enabled.

Comment: Reshaping:

I,m able to see the 'view-code' before extendind the form.

But once I add a extension (right-click in that form at AOT to add extension) the View Code option turns not enabled

May I do some other thing to be able editing the code ?

Comment: You will need to use extensions methods. To do this, you need to create a class and decorate it with an extension attribute for the form you wish to add the code to. Alternatively (depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can use events and just write a custom event handler for whatever control/formdatasource/form event you are trying to customize. See: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/236775 for extending the form class, see: https://community.dynamics.com/enterprise/b/sertansdynamicsax/archive/2017/05/01/ax7-extensibility-part-3-event-handlers-and-delegates-hooks